# Variable info in included PHP file

Tags: php, html, menu, include, code-duplication

Currently I'm using a PHP file wih the footer of my website so I can just include it on every page and change just one file to change the footer on every page of the site.

Now, I would like to do the same with the menu on my site which is like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="active">Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The class active highlights the name of the page the user is on, so if the user is at the 'Menu 2' page of the website the li 'Menu 2' is highlighted. Now I wonder how I can put this menu in a seperate file, like 'menu.php' which I can include in every page, but still be able to change the class="active" to the page the user is at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$open_page = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

and

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" <?php if($open_page == "Menu_1.php") echo " class= 'active' "; ?>>Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" <?php if($open_page == "Menu_2.php") echo " class= 'active' "; ?>>Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" <?php if($open_page == "Menu_3.php") echo " class= 'active' "; ?>>Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" <?php if($open_page == "Menu_4.php") echo " class= 'active' "; ?>>Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Comparing with file-name is not the best-practice & when your project gets heavy, its tough to maintain**

Call the footer from page & pass a page identifier-

```
------ Menu1_page.php --------    
<?php
    require_once 'footer.php';
    getFooter('Menu1');
?>
```

in footer.php, keep the footer within a function

```
---- footer.php -----
<?php
function getFooter($activeid){
   ?>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="<?=($activeid=='Menu1')?'active':''?>">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="<?=($activeid=='Menu2')?'active':''?>">Menu 2</a></li>
        ......
      </ul>
   <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing the `$` from the variables, otherwise this is my preferred solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on how you navigate your page you will have something like
`mydomain.com\index.php?page=whereyouare`.

Then you can access `$_GET['page']` ( even in your footer.php ) to determine on what page you are and if/else it correctly to match class=active

I would not reccomend using global-vars to solve this issue.

Comment: i'm using global variables for this. i don't like sniffing `$_GET` inside the code.